# How to drop multiple tables like %...% in sql server

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to delete particular tables routinely from the `sys.tables` in vb.net. here is code, but it does not work.

```
Try
    Dim MyCommand As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.CommandText = "drop from sys.tables where tabname like '% " & span & "%'"
    Dim result As Integer = MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
    MyCommand.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please never try to change sysviews data. They are for your information. You change that data by executing DDL commands.

In your case you need one `DROP TABLE tablename` per table.
You *can* use sys.tables to get a list of tables to execute a `DROP` against, but the `DROP`s must be separate commands.

Also, it's good to accustom yourself to the correct Dispose pattern:

```
Using MyCommand As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("drop table foo;", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  
End Using
```

Comment: @GSerf @gbn @Philippe Ok I'll change my code around to get table names then loop through them and drop one by one. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to loop and issue single DROP TABLEs explicitly.

You could batch this up into a single call with may DROP TABLE calls.

Edit:

There is also dbo.xp_execresultset that could generate it for you. I don't know if it's still in SQL Server 2005 either to be honest. This is undocumented so YMMV

Answer (score 1):

You should browse sys.tables and find all tables corresponding to your search. You will then, for each one of them, send the following instruction:

```
MyCommand.commandText = "Drop Table '" & tableName & "'"
```